# Spring Boot Integration Test and custom AuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, integration-testing

I have a SpringBoot (version **1.5.21.RELEASE**) app that works fine, but I can not make the integration test to pass.

I have a custom `AuthenticationProvider` where the **authenticate** method returns this:

```java
new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(attempUser.getUsername(), authentication.getCredentials(), grantedAuths);
```

As you can see, the `Principal` is defined to be the **username** of the logged User.

So in my app, whenever I run this:

```java
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String loggedUsername = auth.getPrincipal().toString();
```

The **loggedUsername** is the **username** attribute of the logged User.

I'd like to remark that the app works perfectly fine while running it, the problem is that when I run the test.

When testing the `auth.getPrincipal().toString()` does not return the **username** but the toString() implementation of the `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`

This is my test:

```java
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "cool-username", password = "pwd", authorities = AUTHORITY_ADMIN)
    public void createBound_forAnyUser_ifAdmin() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String loggedUsername = auth.getPrincipal().toString();

        assertThat(loggedUsername).isEqualsTo("cool-username");
    }
}
```

This test (a dummy test to illustrate my problem) fails because **loggedUsername** is actually:

> org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@35c43c96: Username: cool-username; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: USER

I know that a potential solution would be to use **auth.getName()** instead, but this will imply a re-write to the whole working application.

I've try a lot a possible annotations and configurations but all with the same result. What I would like is that the TEST has the SAME SecurityContext that the real world app.

### UPDATE

Maybe I'm doing something wrong and the solution I'm looking for consist in refactor the code.

When the code performs:

```java
String loggedUsername = auth.getPrincipal().toString();
```

then it could do two things:

1- Look-up that username in the DB to get Profile Information

2- Match the user of some other related entity. For example a `Car` that has an `User owner` then it will match `owner.getUsername().equals(loggedUsername)` to grant access for that resource to the requesting User.

Should I do that in any other way? Thank you

### WORKAROUND

As I did not find a solution to my problem (as said before, maybe the problem is the way I'm facing the problem). I decided to mock myself the `SecurityContext` instead of mocking it with the `@WithMockUser`, as suggested by @gtiwari333. So I have this method:

```java
    private void mockSecurityContext(String username, String authority){
        Collection authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority));
        Authentication authentication = Mockito.mock(Authentication.class);
        when(authentication.getPrincipal()).thenReturn(username);
        when(authentication.getAuthorities()).thenReturn(authorities);
        SecurityContext securityContext = Mockito.mock(SecurityContext.class);
        when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authentication);
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
    }
```

In the future I may create a custom annotation like the `@WithMockUser`. If you feel like I'm doing something wrong and I can improve the way I'm doing my test (or even my code implementation) I'll be glad to hear from you

Comment: `@WithMockUser` returns `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` with `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` as Principal. Also, this doesn't consider what Auth Provider/Manager that you are using in the main source.

Comment: So, why do you need to rewrite the whole app?

Comment: As the name suggests `@WithMockUser` is just a mock. It can be used to bypass security checks on Controllers. If you backend code depends on additional user attribute (eg a custom UserDetails class) then you might need to manually create your custom auth object. eg:     `void setCurrentUserWithToken(String username, String token, String... roles) {
        var ctx = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
        ctx.setAuthentication(auth); //custom auth obj
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(ctx);
    }`

Comment: @gtiwari333 there multiple places with a call to `auth.getPrincipal().toString();`. In order to be consistent and make test for them I will need to re-write them. About your other comment, are you telling me that I can overwrite the SecurityContextHolder in my test?

Comment: please see my update in the original question

Comment: And why the security context is not the same when testing than when running my app? If I could achive that, it would be resolved